# how to create html table with css and table properties

Tags: html

I am creating one html table but i am confused with

Can any one help me to create table like attached image with color combinations.

Thank You.

[image]

Comment: use WYSIWYG editor http://ckeditor.com/demo#full

Comment: see [this](http://www.csstablegenerator.com/) link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code. You can change the color according to your choice
`<table border="1" width="50%">

          <tr style="background-color: #090">
              <th>1</th>
              <th>1</th>
              <th>1</th>
              <th>1</th>
          </tr>
          <tr style="background-color: #7aba7b">
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
             <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr style="background-color: #99BC99">
             <td>1</td>
             <td>1</td>
             <td>1</td>
             <td>1</td>
          </tr>
      </table>`

Answer (score 0):

Some basic HTML stuff for tables:

`<table> </table>` = table tag

`<tr> </tr>` = row tag

`<td> </td>` = cell tag

So you put it all together like so:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td> cell content </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Repeat rows and cells as needed. Then add some styling with some CSS or something. Now go try it!

Comment: I want header(vertical) at left side

Comment: make it an extra cell with colspan and use some styling to make the text vertical